How to elevate a view in react native?
I am trying to add elevation so that I can add a effect share below but right now my code isn't adding that effect. I have even tried linear-gradient to add such effect in view but still not able to achieve it.
code:
                <TextInput
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  style={[currentStyles.input, currentStyles.txt, style]}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  onChangeText={onChange}
                  value={value}
                />
              </View>



stlying:
inputView: {
      backgroundColor: "#00000040", // Transparent to show gradient
      height: pixelSizeHorizontal(60),
      paddingHorizontal: pixelSizeHorizontal(10),
      shadowColor: "#747474",
      shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 0 },

      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 0.1,
      elevation: 24,
      borderRadius: 10,
    },
    input: {
      marginTop: pixelSizeVertical(10),
      height: pixelSizeHorizontal(45),
    },



How can add below shared effect in view that wraps TextInput?
